# Why is the question about medical ethics better suited in Psychology SE?

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

Question in question: [How do addiction and fear affect patient's decisional-making capacity?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/posts/25156/revisions)

I agree that it is on-topic Psychology SE, but since [informed consent](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/informed-consent/) and [decision-making capacity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/decision-capacity/) are more about medical contexts (the two links specify that they only discuss in medical context), why isn't the question suited in Medical Sciences SE as well?

Comment: I migrated it to Psych because that seemed to be the more appropriate site since the question is fundamentally a psychological question. Sure, it has importance within the medical community, but I felt it would be better answered in the Psych community. I don't feel all that strongly about it, so if you want it undone I suppose there's probably a way to do that, and I will, but I think that's probably a mistake.

Comment: I did have that feeling as well when picking the site to ask. In the end I want some practically and ethically oriented perspectives, not just a purely theoretical study on decision-making process. I suppose this site is better?

Comment: Okay, I flagged the question and asked them to migrate it back.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your question, yes it has relevance in MedicalSciences.SE but decisions on mental capacity for decision making is formed out of psychological studies.

Psychology is a branch of medical science which is why you can get cross-overs on subjects.

This question to me is purely about psychology rather than medical science in general and therefore more suited to Psychology.SE as originally thought by @Careygregory

As for practical and ethical perspectives, psychology studies things from the practically and ethically oriented perspectives. Ethics is at the forefront of all psychological studies. At least from the Western studies of Psychology. Being from Vietnam, maybe you are exposed to different forms of psychological study but nevertheless, Psychology.SE does not accept answers not based on scientific studies.

Comment: One of the expectation for an *ethical* theory of decision-making capacity is [All-or-nothing assessment](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/decision-capacity/#AllNothAsseRelaPartDeci): "To avoid potentially endless controversy and ensure the smooth operation of the healthcare system, law and practice need a “yes-or-no” verdict about whether a person can make a particular decision for herself or not." I suppose that this is irrelevant at best, and an skewing condition at worst, for a [*psychological* theory of decision-making process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision-making)?

Comment: You are right @Ooker that the legal profession requires a yes or no in courts of law with anything they try to assess within the law. Sometimes it is not so cut and dried as that profession requires when it comes to some areas of psychology or any other area of medical science.

Comment: so what do you think? Would that still be better in Psychology SE?

Comment: Yes I think so @Ooker

Comment: @Ooker It is definitely more appropriate in P&N. As I commented on Nov 22nd, I think migrating it back here was a mistake. But we're not going to play ping pong with it. If you want to ask it on P&N, I'll delete it here and you can create a new question there.

Comment: @CareyGregory perhaps you and ChrisRogers know better than me, so I agree to migrate it to P&N. But why should we close it here and ask a new one there instead of just migrating it? Yes it's a kind of ping pong but it's just this one more time. The reasons are: this one already has 3 votes (a sign for the system to know the quality of the question), and redirection from old links (I advertised the question elsewhere)

Comment: @Ooker I asked the P&N mods for a favor when I asked them to migrate it back. Asking them now to undo that favor would be an annoying waste of their time and would harm not just my credibility with them but this entire site's credibility. Sorry, but you're going to have to delete your question here and create a new one on P&N if you want it back there again.

Comment: @CareyGregory I open a meta question in PN for this: [Would there be any problem with “ping pong” migration?](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2535/12937)

Comment: @Ooker And I replied. You're not going to like my reply but there you have it.